# How to set custom width for part sash container?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm new to Eclipse E4. I'm using part sash container. Is there a way to reduce the width of the left side? By default it container is separated by 50:50. I need that to be 30:70.

Sample screenshot. Here I need to reduce the width of left side. so that right side will have more space:
[image: Sample screenshot. Here I need to reduce the width of left side. so that right side will have more space]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this by putting the relative sizes of the container's children in the `Container Data` field of each child.

So if you have two children for your part sash container the first child could have a Container Data value of '30' and the second child a value of '70'.

Note: It is better to use larger relative size values to get smoother resizing - so something like 3000 and 7000 in this case. It is just the relative values that matter as far as the sizing is concerned.